# once i select date in datepiccker then i again open datepicker it shows the current date not selected date

Tags: android

## here i set my date into date datepicker. once activity open and i select date 26-11-2019 and then i open datepicker it show current date. can u please tell how it will work properly ##

```
public void startCalenderr(View view) {
    // this is my on click method here i open my date picker
    curYear = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    curMonth = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    curDay = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

//this is the dialog for the date picker

    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Main2Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
         // here i set my date into text view
         month += 1;

         String converdate  = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;


         }, curYear, curMonth, curDay);
             dialog.show();
  // here i show my datepicker dialog 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this work for you

```
public void startCalenderr(View view) {

    if(calendar1 == null){
        calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
    if(curYear <1)curYear = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if(curMonth < 1)curMonth = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    if(curDay < 1)curDay = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //this is the dialog for the date picker

    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Main2Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // here i set my date into text view
            month += 1;

            String converdate  = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;

            curYear = year;
            curMont = month;
            curDay = dayOfMonth;
        }, curYear, curMonth, curDay);
             dialog.show();
        // here i show my datepicker dialog 
    }
```

Comment: when i select nov-28-2018 and again i open datepicker it show decemer-28 date

Comment: this happend due to month += 1; replace curMont = month; withe curMont = month -1;

Comment: thanx bro you save my time and life too thnx

Comment: kindly click on the up arrow if this answer help you

Comment: i dont have 15 reputation i am not able to up

Answer (score 0):

Set these parameters

```
curYear, curMonth, curDay
```

at the end of the constructor to the date you like.